# How to store parametric, strongly typed function for a text-based command console

Tags: c++, c++17, interpreter, std-variant

### The use-case

I'm trying to build a small interpreter for a text-based command console.
E.g., say there's a function somewhere:

```cpp
void SetBrightness(float brightness) { /* ... */ }
```

Then it should be possible to write in the console `"SetBrightness 0.5"`, which should result in the above function being called. We can register a command at runtime:

```cpp
void AddCommand(const std::string& command, CommandInterpreterCallback* callback);
```

This function should bind not only a callback function, but also a list of **strongly typed** parameters matching to what the callback expects, to the string `command`. I define a class to hold the callback:

```cpp
using ParamType = std::variant<int32_t, float, std::string, bool>;

class CommandInterpreterCallback
{
public:
    void SetParameters(const std::vector<ParamType>& args)
    {
        mNumParameters = args.size();
        if (mNumParameters >= 1) { mArg1 = args[0]; }
        // ...
    }

    void SetFunction(std::function<void> callback)
    {
        mCallback = callback; // TODO: How to solve this?
    }

private:
    uint8_t mNumParameters = 0;
    ParamType mArg1 = ParamType<bool>; // possibly an array instead here

    std::function<void> mCallback; // TODO: How to solve this?
};
```

### The challenge

I really wish for the parameter passing to be strongly-typed, e.g. the function `SetBrightness()` must have a floating-point number. So if the user writes `"SetBrightness true"`, the function should not get called. Also, I do not want to specify the function parameter as an `std::variant<...>`, because it looks messy and makes calling the function from other parts of the code more difficult.

But I'm not sure how I can declare the `mCallback` member inside the class, because it should somehow be parametric. I understand that I can set the type to e.g. `std::function<void(float)>`. But then, what if I want to bind another function which accepts a boolean?

Maybe I could use `std::variant` as well to specify the type of `mCallback`, but that sounds like an exponential complexity solution.

Is there a good way around these limitations?
I hope I describe the problem well enough.

Comment: Just throwing out ideas... So you have a finite number of commands that your application can interpret? You could perhaps hardcode the association between the first word of each command and the function that will get called as a result? Regarding the parameters, everything comes to you as text so how about testing them with `std::regex`?

Comment: It looks like you want an injective mapping of types of your interpreted language, including function types, to C++ types in the interpreter. This is not going to work because any given C++ program, including your interpreter, only works with a fixed finite set of types, whereas the user of your language can create an unbounded set of types.

Comment: Keywords to research: lexing, parsing, abstract syntax tree.

Comment: I'd make every command vet its untrusted parameters and return (or throw) a syntax error indicator if a bad parameter was provided.  Rather than trying to put that burden on the command interpreter's command wrapper, and then figure out the best way to make that generic and have every command specify its API to the generic preflight checker.

Comment: What you are creating is basically an interpreted strongly typed programming language. If strongly typed is not a strict requirement, consider just using lua .

Comment: @JesperJuhl Which would all start with defining a formal grammar

Comment: @PepijnKramer "Which would all start with defining a formal grammar" - indeed. I should have added "Backus–Naur form" or similar to the list of stuff to research.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yup... Pff been ages since I've done stuff like that... Words like context free come to mind too ;)

Comment: @JesperJuhl isn't it a bit overkill to build a complete language? I know about grammar rules and BN forms (studied at DIKU :) ), but these are simple one-liners with a couple of words separated by space - and that part, which might be called "lexing", is already done. Besides, I need all commands to be dynamic so they may be registered/unregistered arbitrarily at runtime.

Comment: @Eljay I understand that would be the "easy" route, and I will probably do that in case I can't get the generic way to work. Will try to be a bit more creative.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thank you for that rationale! I guess I will move to plan B then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might start with something like:

```
static std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const std::string&)>> commands;

template <typename T>
T extract(std::stringstream& ss)
{
    T t{};
    ss >> t;
    if (!ss) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid argument");
    }
    return t;
}

template <typename...Ts>
void AddCommand(const std::string& name, void(*f)(Ts...))
{
    commands.emplace(name, [f](const std::string& s){
        std::stringstream ss(s);
        try {
            // {..} guarantees left-to-right order.
            std::tuple args = {extract<std::decay_t<Ts>>(ss)...}; 

            std::apply([f](const auto&... args){ f(args...); }, args);
        } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
            std::cout << "ERROR: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }
    });
}

void parseCommand(const std::string& s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    std::string command;
    ss >> command;
    if (auto it = commands.find(command); it != commands.end()) {
        std::string arg;
        std::getline(ss, arg);
        it->second(arg);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Unknown command\n";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ax6rbzWGj)

Comment: This is super elegant! Have never used std::apply before, and std::decay is completely new to me. But I'm not sure I quite follow what you are doing inside `AddCommand`: It looks like you emplace into the map a lambda which returns another lambda?
Anyways, I'm completely blown away by the elegance and the compactness. Thank you!

Comment: I emplace the provided method into a wrapper (a lambda) which parse the string to extract expected parameters. as I store parameter in tuple, I use another lambda to access to element of the tuple. all my lambdas return `void`.

Comment: Are there any functional difference between using `void(*f)(Ts...)` and `std::function<void(Ts...)>` as parameter for `AddCommand`? I'm trying to expand the code to also work with class member functions, for which I need `std::bind`.

Comment: No real functional difference with `std::function` (small extra overhead though). Issue is with deduction of template parameter when you don't provide directly a `std::function`, but indirection might solve that [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8qofT77cT).

Comment: I just tried that, but for some reason I cannot get it to work when I call `AddCommand` with an `std::bind` from a class member function. From how I can gather, I'm using the syntax for `std::bind` in itself correctly, but the conversion to `std::function{f}` fails completely. Would you mind taking a look? Code is here: https://godbolt.org/z/9hnPYT5eo 
And thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: Issue with `std::bind` as for generic lambda, is that the parameter are template, so cannot form a unique `std::function`, using lambda instead of `std::bind` is an alternative: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xzacss3x9).

Comment: Lambda works, but the syntax is a bit more complicated, and unpacking an extra lambda is a bit of unwanted overhead! Anyways, it's really nice to have the flexibility, and I can't thank you enough for all your help! Very grateful.